# NGINX - How to hide real URL

Tags: apache, nginx

I am new to Nginx, currently I have a situation:

- I have a server contains media files (images, ...) which allows to access to contents via URL: `http://10.1.2.3:8080/media/...` (e.g to get an image, we can get from `http://10.1.2.3:8080/media/pix1.jpg`)
- In my web application, the images which are read from that media server will be displayed through HTML tag: `<img src="http://10.1.2.3:8080/media/pix1.jpg" ... />`

What I want it to be...:

- Using Nginx, I want to hide the real path to these images, it should be in HTML source: `<img src="media/pix1.jgp... />` instead of `<img src="http://10.1.2.3:8080/media/pix1.jpg ... />`
- I want to have map URL between `http://10.1.2.3:8080/media` and media

Note that I used Apache 2.4.7 before, I resolved by using `ProxyHTMLURL`

Comment: Do you serve html page from the same server?

Comment: No, the JSP page is on another server Alexey

Comment: I guess you need http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Comment: whether you want to parse the HTML-content before output?